# Sort NSMutableDictionary by NSNumber-type keys

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

I need to set source array with custom `UITableVIewCells` for `UITableView`. At start I am creating dynamically keys(`NSNumber`-indexes for cells, lot of options here) and adding them using

```
[dict1 setObject:cell forKey:[self returnCurrentIndex:nsnumberValue isCurrent:YES]];
```

to sort dictionary by indexes later.
Unexpectedly

```
NSArray *sortedKeysArray = [dict1 keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

causes exception

> '-[PTDigitInputCell copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x6ecf710'

I understand that this method tryng to sort dictionary by values(custom tableView cell`s in my case) but not the keys(NSNumbers), and in Apple documentationI can't find method what will be sort by keys. Does it exist, or how can I solve this?

Comment: It looks like some of your keys may be PTDigitInputCell objects.

Comment: Interesting, why do you think so?

Comment: Well, I take that back.  Most likely some of your values are PTDigitInputCell objects, and the sort is trying to copy them, since that sort sorts on the values, not the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overthinked this. Just take all keys and then sort array:

```
NSArray *sortedKeysArray = [[dict1 allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```